# Entity Framework: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I want to update my migrated database on my Asp.Net Core MVC Application, but I get the following error when I try to do this:

I have already tried a few tutorials or forum posts but unfortunately it didn't work. Could someone help me please?

That's my Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using PlaudertischSoftware.Models;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace PlaudertischSoftware
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddDbContext<DatenbankKontext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"));
            });

        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PlaudertischSoftware.Models;
using System.IO;

namespace PlaudertischSoftware
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseKestrel()
               .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .UseIISIntegration()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

My ContextFactory:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using PlaudertischSoftware.Models;

namespace PlaudertischSoftware
{
    public class DatenbankKontextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DatenbankKontext>
    {
        public DatenbankKontext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatenbankKontext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");

            return new DatenbankKontext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

That's my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyConnectionString;Integrated Security=True"
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't have a .mdf File. In my Application the Controller creates a database and updates it dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
    public DatenbankKontext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatenbankKontext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        return new DatenbankKontext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
```

That `UseSqlServer` is expecting an actual connection string, and you're passing it a string of `"MyConnectionString"` which is only the name you've called your connection string config entry, but `UseSqlServer` won't take it and go rummaging in your appsettings.connectionstrings looking for something with that name; it'll just take it as if it were a connection string and try to use it

I would have expected it to look more like your other line (in the services registration) which is:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
```

Actually, I'm not even really sure what your DatenbankKontextFactory is hoping to do that the DbContext creator you've already registered with DI isn't doing? If you want a DbContext for some reason and the one provided for you by DI is no good (wrong scope?) then you can ask DI to make you another one, perhaps with a different scope

Comment: Oh yes you're right. The DatenbankKontextFactory is completely useless. I already have a dbcontext. I had that from some confusing internet tutorials